# Adding a checkbox inside a FusionCharts chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, fusioncharts

I have a fusionCharts bar chart and would like to add a checkbox inside it, so that when a user ticks the check box the chart refreshes with a different set of data and when the user unticks it the original data set appears.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on "like to add a checkbox inside it"? Are you stuck at implementing the check-box functionality or are you stuck at getting the checkbox draw **inside** a chart? A bit more elaborate question will be more helpful for us and the StackOverFlow community. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this demo from the **FusionCharts Features Gallery** - http://www.fusioncharts.com/features/client-side-data-update/

It seems the implementation in this demo is similar to your requirements. View the source and check it out.